# about complicated biz logic in async

Tags: node.js, async.js

I am new in node.js and have some confusied questions about async. See the code below.

```
var async = require('async');

const func = function func(cb) {
        cb(null, 'hello');
}
const func1 = function func1(param1, cb) {
        console.log(param1);
        cb(null, 'hello', 'world');
}
const func2 = function func2(param1, param2, cb) {
        console.log(param1, ' ', param2);
        cb(null, 'result');
}
async.waterfall([func, func1, func2], (err, result)=> {
        console.log(result);
});
```

Yes, we know the function will run one by one. My question is, if I have some complicated condition logic based on different result from the function. Is that mean I have to use await and re-write the return code for the functions?

```
async function doIt() {
    const t= await func(parms);
    ... biz logic ...
    const t1= await func1(t);
    ... biz logic ...
    const t2= await func2(t1);
    ... biz logic ...    
}
doIt();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option (disclaimer: not very elegant...) would be to define variables at the global scope (so they are accessible everywhere), and then use `async.series` to perform any sequential tasks or complex logic you need to perform:

```
    var async = require('async');

    var param1;
    ...
    var result;


    async.series([
        function(cb) {
            func(function() { 
                 param1 = ...;
                 cb(null);
            }
        },
        function(cb)
            // biz logic
        },
        function(cb) {
             func1(param1, function() {
                 cb();
             }
        },
        // etc.
    ], function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
        } else {
            console.log(result);
        }
   });
```

Otherwise, you can use promises, which will be more readable.